# Having trouble simulating a two-stage differential amplifier in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, simulation, differential-amplifier

The following is an LTspice simulation for a two-stage differential amplifier.

[image]

The simulation takes hours. What am I doing wrong?

Spice netlist:

```
M1 N003 N001 N005 N003 PMOS
M2 N003 N002 N006 N003 PMOS
M3 N003 P001 Vout- N003 PMOS
M4 N003 N004 Vout+ N003 PMOS
M5 N005 N008 N011 0 NMOS
M6 N006 N009 N011 0 NMOS
I1 N011 0 0.45m
M7 Vout+ N012 0 0 NMOS
M8 Vout- N013 0 0 NMOS
V1 N003 0 3.3
R1 N003 N012 10Meg
R2 N012 0 10Meg
R3 N003 N013 10Meg
R4 N013 0 10Meg
R5 N003 N001 10Meg
R6 N001 0 10Meg
R7 N003 N002 10Meg
R8 N002 0 10Meg
Vin+ N007 0 SINE(0 10m 1Meg)
Vin- N010 0 SINE(0 10m 1Meg 0 0 180)
R9 N003 N008 10Meg
R10 N008 0 10Meg
R11 N003 N009 10Meg
R12 N009 0 10Meg
C1 N008 N007 1m
C2 N010 N009 1m
C3 N005 N004 1m
C4 P001 N006 1m
.model NMOS NMOS
.model PMOS PMOS
.lib C:\Users\jackh\Documents\LTspiceXVII\lib\cmp\standard.mos
.MODEL pmos pmos(kp=2935u,vto=-0.4, lambda =0.2)
.MODEL nmos nmos(kp=1700.84u,vto=0.4, lambda = 0.1)
.tran 0 1031us 1028us
.backanno
.end
```

The gain is way too small when I change the capacitor to 1.59 nF. What's wrong?

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 1420 680
WIRE 16 48 -352 48
WIRE 688 48 176 48
WIRE -512 64 -608 64
WIRE -448 64 -512 64
WIRE -272 64 -448 64
WIRE -96 64 -272 64
WIRE -48 64 -96 64
WIRE 64 64 -48 64
WIRE 112 64 64 64
WIRE 256 64 112 64
WIRE 320 64 256 64
WIRE 416 64 320 64
WIRE 464 64 416 64
WIRE 608 64 464 64
WIRE 736 64 608 64
WIRE 832 64 736 64
WIRE 112 112 112 64
WIRE 112 112 64 112
WIRE 320 112 320 64
WIRE 320 112 256 112
WIRE -32 144 -160 144
WIRE 16 144 16 48
WIRE 176 144 176 48
WIRE 208 144 176 144
WIRE -608 160 -608 144
WIRE -448 160 -448 144
WIRE -352 160 -352 48
WIRE -352 160 -448 160
WIRE -272 160 -272 64
WIRE 608 160 608 64
WIRE 688 160 688 48
WIRE 736 160 736 144
WIRE 736 160 688 160
WIRE -96 176 -96 64
WIRE 416 176 416 64
WIRE 832 176 832 64
WIRE -448 192 -448 160
WIRE 736 192 736 160
WIRE -512 208 -512 64
WIRE -48 224 -48 64
WIRE -48 224 -96 224
WIRE -32 224 -32 144
WIRE 64 224 64 160
WIRE 64 224 32 224
WIRE 464 224 464 64
WIRE 464 224 416 224
WIRE -160 256 -160 144
WIRE -144 256 -160 256
WIRE 256 256 256 160
WIRE 304 256 256 256
WIRE -448 288 -448 272
WIRE 64 288 64 224
WIRE 256 288 256 256
WIRE 736 288 736 272
WIRE -96 336 -96 272
WIRE -96 336 -144 336
WIRE 112 336 64 336
WIRE 304 336 256 336
WIRE 416 336 416 272
WIRE 448 336 416 336
WIRE -752 368 -752 320
WIRE -672 368 -752 368
WIRE -512 368 -512 288
WIRE -512 368 -608 368
WIRE 16 368 -512 368
WIRE 832 368 832 256
WIRE 832 368 352 368
WIRE 928 368 832 368
WIRE 1056 368 1056 320
WIRE 1056 368 992 368
WIRE -752 384 -752 368
WIRE 144 384 64 384
WIRE 256 384 144 384
WIRE -96 400 -96 336
WIRE 208 400 208 368
WIRE 352 400 352 368
WIRE 352 400 208 400
WIRE 416 400 416 336
WIRE -512 416 -512 368
WIRE 144 416 144 384
WIRE 832 416 832 368
WIRE 0 448 -96 448
WIRE 528 448 416 448
WIRE -272 480 -272 240
WIRE -144 480 -272 480
WIRE 1056 480 1056 448
WIRE -752 496 -752 464
WIRE -96 512 -96 496
WIRE 0 512 0 448
WIRE 0 512 -96 512
WIRE 112 512 112 336
WIRE 144 512 144 496
WIRE 144 512 112 512
WIRE 304 512 304 336
WIRE 304 512 144 512
WIRE 368 512 368 480
WIRE 608 512 608 240
WIRE 608 512 368 512
WIRE -512 528 -512 496
WIRE 416 528 416 496
WIRE 528 528 528 448
WIRE 528 528 416 528
WIRE 832 528 832 496
WIRE -272 544 -272 480
WIRE -96 544 -96 512
WIRE 144 544 144 512
WIRE 608 544 608 512
WIRE 416 560 416 528
WIRE -272 640 -272 624
WIRE 608 640 608 624
FLAG 144 544 0
FLAG -96 544 0
FLAG 416 560 0
FLAG -608 160 0
FLAG 448 336 Vout-
IOPIN 448 336 Out
FLAG -144 336 Vout+
IOPIN -144 336 In
FLAG -272 640 0
FLAG 608 640 0
FLAG -448 288 0
FLAG 736 288 0
FLAG -752 496 0
FLAG 1056 480 0
FLAG 832 528 0
FLAG -512 528 0
FLAG 1056 320 vi-
IOPIN 1056 320 BiDir
FLAG -752 320 vi+
IOPIN -752 320 BiDir
SYMBOL pmos4 16 64 R0
SYMATTR InstName M1
SYMBOL pmos4 208 64 R0
SYMATTR InstName M2
SYMBOL pmos4 368 176 R0
SYMATTR InstName M3
SYMBOL pmos4 -144 176 R0
SYMATTR InstName M4
SYMBOL nmos4 16 288 R0
SYMATTR InstName M5
SYMBOL nmos4 208 288 R0
SYMATTR InstName M6
SYMBOL current 144 416 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 24 108 Left 2
SYMATTR SpiceLine load
SYMATTR InstName I1
SYMATTR Value 0.45m
SYMBOL nmos4 -144 400 R0
SYMATTR InstName M7
SYMBOL nmos4 368 400 R0
SYMATTR InstName M8
SYMBOL voltage -608 48 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 3.3
SYMBOL res -288 144 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 10Meg
SYMBOL res -288 528 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 10Meg
SYMBOL res 592 144 R0
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 10Meg
SYMBOL res 592 528 R0
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value 10Meg
SYMBOL res -464 48 R0
SYMATTR InstName R5
SYMATTR Value 10Meg
SYMBOL res -464 176 R0
SYMATTR InstName R6
SYMATTR Value 10Meg
SYMBOL res 720 48 R0
SYMATTR InstName R7
SYMATTR Value 10Meg
SYMBOL res 720 176 R0
SYMATTR InstName R8
SYMATTR Value 10Meg
SYMBOL voltage -752 368 R0
WINDOW 3 -223 96 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value SINE(0 10m 1Meg)
SYMATTR InstName Vin+
SYMBOL voltage 1056 352 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName Vin-
SYMATTR Value SINE(0 10m 1Meg 0 0 180)
SYMBOL res -528 192 R0
WINDOW 3 -78 72 Left 2
SYMATTR Value 10Meg
SYMATTR InstName R9
SYMBOL res -528 400 R0
SYMATTR InstName R10
SYMATTR Value 10Meg
SYMBOL res 816 160 R0
SYMATTR InstName R11
SYMATTR Value 10Meg
SYMBOL res 816 400 R0
SYMATTR InstName R12
SYMATTR Value 10Meg
SYMBOL cap -608 352 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName 100k
SYMATTR Value 1µ
SYMBOL cap 992 352 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMATTR Value 1µ
SYMBOL cap 32 208 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 29 13 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName C3
SYMATTR Value 1µ
SYMBOL cap 368 240 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName C4
SYMATTR Value 1µ
TEXT -176 -24 Left 2 !.MODEL pmos pmos(kp=200u,vto=-0.4, lambda =0.2)
TEXT -176 0 Left 2 !.MODEL nmos nmos(kp=200u,vto=0.4, lambda = 0.1)
TEXT -640 592 Left 2 !.tran 0 1031us 1028us
TEXT -88 600 Left 2 !.meas Vo pp V(vout+) - V(vout-);
TEXT -88 632 Left 2 !.meas Vi pp V(vi+) - V(vi-);
TEXT -88 656 Left 2 !.meas Av param Vo/Vi;
```

Comment: what maximum time step are you running?

Comment: @Andyaka Default one

Comment: Capacitive C1, C2, C3 and C4 are 1mF. Why so high ... in transient simulation.

Comment: @Antonio51 What value do you recommend for capacitors?

Comment: You have just after that capacitors C1 & C2, two resistors (in "parallel" ) of value 10 MegOhm. the impedance of the capacitor should be some 100 kOhm at the frequency of 1 MHz in use ... C3 and C4 should be also "lower".

Comment: @Antonio51 That would be around 1.59 nF. Am I correct?

Comment: This should be correct. But for a "good" study, you should first do a DC Analysis to see if the DC quiet points are ok for all mosfets. Then do an AC analysis ... and finally a TRANsient analysis ... it is "longer" than you think ...

Comment: This circuit will never work. Also, notice that the M4 and M3 gates are floating. What did you want to achieve in the first place?

Comment: @G36 Two stage differential amplifier. How to avoid M4 and M3 floating

Comment: You can probably DC couple by removing these capacitors C3, C4 or biasing these transistors M3, M4.

Comment: @internet Do you mean I should also include a DC voltage divider for M3,M4?

Comment: Another generic tip for IC circuits like these is to flag I1 as a load (there’s a checkbox in the advanced menu) or build it as a current mirror out of MOSFETs.

Comment: @SteKulov Any schematics I can look at for your tip?

Comment: If you have to ask I would just flag it as load.

Comment: @SteKulov How can I flag I1 as a load? Any concrete tutorials?

Comment: Yeah, here.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfQEc.png  https://i.stack.imgur.com/JysGY.png

Comment: @SteKulov I tried your method. But gain is still less than 1

Comment: I wasn’t proposing a solution to your problem. I said it was a generic tip for constructing these kinds of IC circuits. I think you should address the other comments regarding the floating gates. If you’re still stuck you can copy/paste the text of the contents of your `.asc` file so someone can try messing around with it

Comment: @SteKulov I have posted my asc file now. Please check what's wrong here if you have time